# Ruby on Rails Graphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a rails app running which is monitoring several websites by making a HTTP request to a specified URL.
The application also gets the DNS response time and Server Response Time - I wanted to construct a graph to show the response time over x period.
I was looking for a graph like the bandwidth graphs you often see, something like this: https://www.ubiquityservers.com/pdf/bandwidth%20graph%20daily%20view.png

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/gallery/) a flash solution to make graphs.

Or may be you can find exactly what you want on [ruby-toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/graphing.html), they are a complete list of gems to make graph in a rails app.

Answer (score 1):

You may like [Open Flash Chart Plugin](http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart)